# Minimization of a weighted least-squares problem by Lagrange multiplier method

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Problem:

Let $Y = (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i =1$ and $k \geq 0$. Show that $x=Yk$ is a minimizer for $h(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i \left\|x-y_i \right\|_{2}^{2}.$

My trial:

Define the Lagrange function:
$$\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i \left\|x-y_i \right\|_{2}^{2} - \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i-1.$$

Then, differentiating with respect to $x$ and set it to be zero:

$$\nabla \mathcal{L}_{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i \left\|x-y_i \right\|_{2} = 0.$$

My puzzle is that:

(1) Should I thus set $x=y_i$ as the solution of $\nabla \mathcal{L}_{x}=0$?

(2) How does this relate to the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i =1$?

I appreciate so much for your help.

Comment: You're not taking the derivative properly. For instance, the derivative of $\|x-y_i\|_2^2$ is just $2(x-y_i)$.

Comment: @michael Thanks for your comment but in the Lagrange function, there is a $\dfrac{1}{2}$ in the first term and the derivative should be correct?

Comment: Well sure you have to account for the 1/2 term. But you have made no edit. The derivative is wrong.

Comment: @michael Indeed I am not sure which point I made the mistake. Would you please point it out and tell me how to continue to prove the result $x=Yk$ is the minimizer of the objective function? Many thanks.

Comment: I told you: the derivative (gradient, actually) of $\|x-y_i\|_2^2$ is just $2(x-y_i)$. Note that *the norm is gone*. The derivative is *not* $2\|x-y_i\|_2$ as you seem to indicate.

Comment: @michael Thanks again but the Lagrangian function defined is $$\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i \left\|x-y_i \right\|_{2}^{2} - \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i-1.$$

Then the derivative should be like this?

$$\nabla \mathcal{L}_{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i \left (x-y_i \right ) = 0.$$

Comment: I'm afraid we are talking past each other. I can't help further, I'm sorry.

Comment: If $ {k}_{i} $ are not given I'm not sure this is a convex optimization problem.